# How to return Stream<Employee> using Spring JPA while limiting results returned?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA repository and I am streaming results from a query method:

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM EmployeeEntity")
    Stream<Employee> streamEmployees();
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to set a limit for the stream dynamically, using a parameter:

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM EmployeeEntity limit :limit")
    Stream<Employee> streamEmployees(@Param("limit") int limit);
}
```

Is it possible? I know you can use a return type of stream, but I want to limit the returned results. I want to avoid the use of native queries.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using query, which could raised a vulnerability, you can use the pageable class which will contains the result as a content which can be changed to a stream.
to create the page :

```
Pageable page = PageRequest.of(pageNo,sizeNo);
```

and the jpa method could be like :

```
Page<Employee> findAll(Pageable page);
```

so you can set the page to zero and the size to the limit you wish.

more explain :
the Page is inherited from Slics which is inherited from Streamable.
so you can call `stream()` function from the Page object.